# Qualitative analysis of a firstorder non-linear ODE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a>0$, $\alpha$ be a function with $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}\alpha(t)=0$ and $u_0>0$ $\Rightarrow$ The solution of $$\left\{\begin{matrix}u'&=&\overbrace{\alpha(t)u-au^2}^{=:f(t,u)}&,&t>0\\u(0)&=&u_0\end{matrix}\right.$$
satisfies $$\lim_{t\to\infty}u(t)=0\tag{1}$$

*Proof*: First of all, we can obtain $u\ge 0$ in $(0,T_\max)$ by comparison principle. Since we've got $a>0$ this yields $$u'\le\alpha(t)u\to 0\;\;\;\text{for }t\to\infty$$ However, I got stuck at this point.

How do I need to proceed? With (1) in mind, I suppose one needs to show $u'<0$ in $(0,T_\max)$, but I'm unable to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :

Prove that in an non trivial solution (ie : a non constant solution), you always have $u \neq 0$ (Picard–Lindelöf theorem theorem).
Then consider $v(t)=\frac{1}{u(t)}$

Comment: Which theorem are you talking about and what would be a trivial solution here?

Comment: I was talking about the Picard–Lindelöf theorem (which is named after Cauchy in some countries). This theorem can allow you to state that any solution that would be equal to 0 for some value of t would be equal to 0 for all t. So you can conclude that either u is 0 everywhere, or it is 0 nowhere.

Comment: Your approach yields $$v'=-\frac{u'}{u^2}=a-\frac{\alpha(t)}{u}\to a>0\;\;\;\text{for }t\to\infty$$ for $u\not\equiv 0$. But $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}v(t)=\infty$ doesn't immediately follow. What do we need to do next?

Comment: you should substitute u everywhere : $v'=-\frac{u'}{u^2}=a-\alpha(t) \cdot v$. So you just have to solve this first order linear equation, which i assume you can solve. Can you ?